# OWIN OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, owin

I've been looking around for information on this for a little while and keep seeing what appears to be how to set up a OAuth2 server in ASP.NET.

What I want is like the  "app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication" where I can use an external login service but that service is standard OAuth2 and not one of the built in providers. I'm not finding a lot of documentation on that subject and would like it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really such a thing as a standard oauth2 provider when you are looking for authentication. See http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/02/oauth-2-0-and-sign-in-4/ for a discussion about it. 
Which providers were you looking to support?